# using http service on orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to set up http service to be consumed within my form builder control element, and passing parameter from a text field. But still no output is displayed.

Here is the form I created on orbeon.com website to describe (application and form name is csahat) : 
http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/0860411ecf1bff6128bd802784ee22a33b0bab68

[http service description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rci9g.jpg)

resource URL: 
http://localhost:3000/posts

Response body:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "json-server",
    "author": "typicode"
  }
]
```

Service Response Action
/response/row/title

Why I still can't display the value on the output control? 
Is there a way to debug to see what went wrong?

Comment: Update: orbeon form installed locally that's why the http service pointing to localhost. I created the form in demo.orbeon.form so anyone can easily see my configuration

Answer (score 1):

Calls to services are made from the server running Orbeon Forms, so if you're running Orbeon Forms on `http://demo.orbeon.com/`, you can't call a service you have on your own machine using `http://localhost:3000/`. This URL will hit the `demo.orbeon.com` server, which most likely doesn't have anything running on its 3000 port.

Instead, you'll most likely want to install Orbeon Forms locally. This will also allow you to monitor the `orbeon.log` in case calling the service fails, as you'll find more detailed information there.

Comment: Yes, the orbeon form installed locally that's why the service is in localhost. I creeated the form in demo.orbeon.com so it's easy for anyone to see my set up

Comment: Got it @Chris. Then I would recommend you set your logging per the [dev config](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html#development-configuration), run a `tail -f orbeon.log` (or equivalent on your OS), reproduce the issue, and check if you see anything useful in the log. You'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: I created the form using Form Builder instead of XForm, will it still applicable?

Comment: @Chris, yes: your form created with Form Builder uses XForms, and specifically the `xf:submission`, which when it runs logs lots of useful debugging information in the `orbeon.log`. You'll let me know what you find there.

Comment: @Chris Have you figured out how to populate call your service, or do you still have an issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your response path, `/response/row/title` is incorrect.

You are receiving a JSON object back, which maps to the following XML data structure:

```
<json type="array">
    <_ type="object">
        <id type="number">1</id>
        <title>json-server</title>
        <author>typicode</author>
    </_>
</json>
```

So to access the title of the first array item, you can write:

```
/json/_[1]/title
```

Comment: how do I know the mapping to XML if I have different JSON object?

Comment: Ideally, Form Builder should help you with that better. The mapping is pretty simple and you can find its descriptions [in the XForms 2.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0#External_JSON_values).